# What's the best way to add an entity (of a specific type) selector to a form?

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I can achieve what I want by using the `EntityFieldQuery` and transforming it to be the right format for a radio options array. 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're operating on an entity, you can just use an [Entityreference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field which will do it for you.

If not, then yes, write it yourself and use `EntityFieldQuery`. Just watch out, `entityCondition('bundle')` is broken for comments and taxonomy terms, and entity access is non-existent (so it will show all users instead of the non-blocked ones, etc).
Entityreference implements workarounds for this (until it gets fixed in core), so you can take a look and borrow that code if needed.